# Build a system using MiNiFi C2 server

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I follow the steps.

1. Downloaded MiNiFi c2 server in Windows where my NiFi is running.
2. Created a template using NiFi UI with name given `examplename iot-minifi-raspberry-agent.v1`
3. Canged MiNiFi c2 property port - 8080 (U was also getting port 10080 is already in use)
4. Changed minifi-c2-context.xml property

   ```
   <constructor-arg> <value>http://localhost:9090/nifi/</value> </constructor-arg> in this url my nifi is working,so this only changed
   ```
5. My MiNiFi is running in different Windows machine. There I changed bootstrap property like below

   ```
   ---------------------------------------*****--------------
   # Hostname on which to pull configurations from
   nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.hostname=localhost

   # Port on which to pull configurations from
   nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.port=8080

   # Path to pull configurations from
   minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.path=/c2/config

   # Query string to pull configurations with
   nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.query=class=iot-minifi-raspberry-agent ----// name of my template ?? should i use version also like .v1

   # Period on which to pull configurations from, defaults to 5 minutes if commented out nifi.minifi.notifier.ingestors.pull.http.period.ms=60000

   -----------------------------------*****-------------------
   ```
6. Now all changes are done I check whether my changes are done correctly by hitting below URL

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/c2/config?class=iot-minifi-raspberry-agent.v1&version=1
   ```

   I can see yml is showing but that is already present in MiNiFi

   ```
   c2 -->files folder
   ```

What am I doing wrong or where is my understanding incorrect?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am getting below error :2018-11-12 16:37:28,189 WARN [pool-2-thread-1] o.a.n.m.b.c.i.PullHttpChangeIngestor Hit an exception while trying to pull
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:10080
 at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:189)

Comment: not clear what's the problem...

Comment: Hi Daggett ,I am doing a poc where i m taking data from minifi to nifi .for that i using minifi c2 server for command and control but i am getting above error.

Comment: Hi Daggett .my error is related below link community.hortonworks.com/answers/227348/view.html

Answer (score 0):

You say that your minifi is running on diffeent machine, So your bootstrap configuration is wrong.
Your host name to pull configurations from must be on which your minifi-c2 server is running and not local.
This should work.